# Is it possible to re-submit the manuscript again without being restricted to a specific time?

Tags: peer-review, journals, paper-submission

My manuscript was submitted to a reputable magazine. During the revision process, I revised the manuscript again. When the reviewers finished making changes, the comments I received matched the ones I edited exactly. The question now is whether I should resubmit the manuscript right away or wait a little longer.

Comment: There is no reason to wait unnecessarily. But it looks like you submitted your manuscript prematurely. You should avoid doing that in the future.